# MySql Query Timed Out in Live but not in Local

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-optimization

We are using MySQL InnoDB.

We have a query looks like this.

In our live environment, this query took more than 30 seconds to complete.

```
select  count(*) as aggregate
    from  `parents`
    where  exists (
        SELECT  *
            from  `childs`
            where  `parents`.`id` = `childs`.`parent_id`
              and  exists (
                SELECT  *
                    from  `users`
                    where  `childs`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
                      and  `id` = '123456' )
              and  `status` = 'OK' )
```

And so we have exported the whole database and import into to our local mysql database.
And surprisingly, it took almost instant to get the same query results.

As so we suspect the table was not optimized and we have done the following.

```
optimize table users;
optimize table parents;
optimize table childs;
```

Unfortunately the query speed didn't improve.

Can anyone see what could goes wrong?

And why does export/import in local (with exactly same structure data) have almost instant query and the live took almost 30-60 seconds to complete?

---

EXPLAIN on both local and live shows a difference,
one of the DEPENDENT SUBQUERY for possible keys relating the parents and child table shows

```
Using where; FirstMatch(closing_batches)
```

but the live shows only `Using where` without the FirstMatch.

Comment: Can you do an EXPLAIN on both live and local to see whether the same execution plan is applied?

Comment: Hi @Jacob thanks for your tip, I have done an EXPLAIN like you have suggested and found that "FirstMatch" is missing. What could have caused this?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually probably get all the data from a single query without even using the parents or user table -- IF the "Status" field is in the childs table.

From basic Transitive association,

```
if A = B and B = C, then A = C.
```

You are joining from Child to User by ID, then looking at the User ID = "123456".

This is the same as just asking for Childs.User_ID = "123456".

Likewise, from the Child joined to the parent by the Child.Parent_ID, it looks like your query is trying to get a count of distinct parent IDs that are associated with given childs.

So, the following SHOULD be able to get what you need.

```
select 
        count( distinct c.Parent_id ) Aggregate
    from
        childs c
    where
            c.user_id = '123456'
        AND c.status = 'OK'
```

if the status field is on the PARENT table, you will need to join to that

```
select 
        count( distinct c.Parent_id ) Aggregate
    from
        childs c
            join parents p
                on c.parent_id = p.id
                AND p.status = 'OK'
    where
            c.user_id = '123456'
```

For performance, I would ALSO have an index on the childs table on ( user_id, parent_id ).  This can significantly optimize the query too.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably equivalent:

```
select  count(*) as aggregate
    from  `parents` AS p
    where  exists (
        SELECT  *
            from  `childs` AS c
            JOIN  users AS u  ON c.user_id = u.id
            WHERE  c.user_id = 123456
              AND  p.`id` = c.`parent_id`
              and  `status` = 'OK' 
        )
```

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is rarely useful.

Which table is `status` in?

Comment: Query is generated by Laravel's Eloquent. `status` is column of `parents`. The same query yields results at local (dump from production and imported to local) almost instantly but just not in the production.

Comment: @Gab - OK.  Now I vote for DRapp's second query.  If Eloquent cannot generate something reasonably close to that, the I suggest that it is "getting in the way".  Currently it seems sloppy to have a subquery, `LEFT`, and the unnecessary `Users`.